# What does "well defined composition" mean for a catagory with a congruence?

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category with congruence ~, and let $[f]$ denote the
equivalence class of a morphism $f$. Define $C'$ as follows:

$$obj C' = obj C$$
$$Hom_{C'} = \{[f] : f \in Hom_{C}(A,B)\}$$
$$[g] \circ [f] = [g \circ f]$$

The book states that this property from the definition of congruence:
$f$ ~ $f'$ and $g$ ~ $g'$ and $g \circ f$ exists imply that $g \circ f$ ~ $g' \circ f'$, shows that composition in $C'$ is well defined.

What does it mean for composition of morphisms to be well defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For quotients in general, a function $f : X/{\sim}\to Y$ is **well-defined** if it doesn't distinguish between representatives of equivalence classes.  That is, if if $x \sim y$ then $f(x)=f(y)$.  If $Y$ itself is a quotient, i.e. $Y = Z/{\approx}$, then $f(x) = f(y)$ means $[z]=f(x)$ and $[z']=f(y)$ and so $[z]=[z']$ which means $z \approx z'$.

So working entirely at the level of representatives, a function $g : A/{\sim} \to B/{\approx}$ is a function $\bar g : A \to B$ such that $\forall a,a'\in A.a\sim a' \implies f(a)\approx f(a')$.

In this case, it's composition as a (family of) function(s) $$\circ : (\text{Hom}(B,C)/{\sim})\times(\text{Hom}(A,B)/{\sim})\to\text{Hom}(A,C)/{\sim}$$ which has an underlying function $$\bar\circ : \text{Hom}(B,C)\times\text{Hom}(A,B)\to\text{Hom}(A,C)$$ which must satisfy the rules you laid out.